# how can i make this script show the value of the var "per" based on the new value of the var "a" that raise on every click

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to display a 'clicker' variable, storing the number of clicks on a certain element, and then display it when i click on another element.

`per = a * 6.6666` so I tried again and it wont work the result stay 0 but if I change the value of a to 1 it shows 6.6666 so the calculation is working fine but it is not taking the value of a based on how many times I click it just take the value I gave in the script ...

```
    var a =  0 ;
    const six = 6.6666;
            
    var per = a * six;

    $(".mychoice").click(function () {
        (a++);
    });

    $(".show").click(function () {
        $("#ss").text( per );
    });
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its title is not going to help anybody else.

Comment: Hello Fadix :-) Please put some punctuation in your sentences, it shows a minimum respect to the readers trying to help you :-) Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> var per = a * six;
> ```

The calculation is executed and stored in the `per` variable as soon as the line is executed, not when you reference the `per` variable.

If you want to calculate the value at a later time, use an [(arrow) function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead.

```
// define `per` as arrow function with 0 arguments
var per = () => a * six;
```

Then you evoke the function when you need the result:

```
$(".show").click(function () {
    $("#ss").text( per() );
});
```

---

In this scenario doing the calculation directly, without defining a function, might be cleaner.

```
$(".show").click(function () {
    $("#ss").text(a * six);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Calculations are done when you tell them to be done.

If you change the value of `a` in a click event, then that value doesn't travel back through time so that `a` is the new value back when you read it and used it to multiply `six`.

If you want to redo that calculation when something is clicked then you need to write that expression in that click event handler function.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `a` and `per` are two distinct locations in memory, therefore, you have to update the `per` variable along with the `a` variable.

```
var a = 0;
const six = 6.6666;
var per = a * six;
$(".mychoice").click(function () {
    (a++);
    // memory location labelled "a" has changed
    // update memory location labelled "per" accordingly
    per = a * six;
});

$(".show").click(function () {
    $("#ss").text(per);
});
```